# Text field in safari browser don't stay equal on height to button beside when zooming out

Tags: html, css, safari, zooming, textfield

I have a text field with a image button next to it. When I zoom out in Safari Browser the text field isn't equal on height to the image button beside it. I only have this problem on the Safari Browser and not in IE, Mozilla, Chrome, and Opera.

**html**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="search_bar">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.somerandomdude.com/wp-content/uploads/search-icon.png">
</form>
```

**css**

```
form input[type=text]{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 34px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

form input[type=image]{
    float: left;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
}
```

[Screenshots](http://postimg.org/gallery/8sebypwk/)
first: Chrome no zoom
second: Chrome zoom-out
third: Safari no zoom
fourth: Safari zoom-out

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5de9M/)

So do anyone know a way to fixed this?

Comment: Curious, I'm running Safari and I don't see any problem... Did you try  to simply set a `margin: 0px;` to your `form input[type=image]`?

Comment: Still having the same problem.. Are you sure you are zooming out to the max?

Comment: I was trying to zoom in JSFiddle but it's apparently not possible (it's possible but nothing happens in the view)... My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think the problem is due to the fact that Safari uses only int values to position it's elements and the other browsers uses floats values... So when you zoom the value is rounded for all browsers except Safari.
So I suggest you to use the same size to your inputs like set a `height: 36px;` to your `form input[type=text]` (note that you'll need to use a `padding: 0px;` in that case). So your CSS began:

```
body{
    background: #4679bd;
}

form input[type=text]{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 36px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

form input[type=image]{
    float: left;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
}
```

I hope it will work. Have a nice day =) !

Comment: You solve it, thank you so much! So simple yet so effective, and a great explanation too.